# What options do I have when my boss is rude and I cannot leave my job?

Tags: new-job, manager, bullying

I joined a company as an employee a month ago. I signed a 6 months contract, so I can't leave this job. It was nice at work in the beginning, but now my boss has started overburdening me. He is also cutting off my salary, saying I am a lazy worker, although I did my best and do my work on time. He is very rude to me, in a sense that his behaviour is normal with other workers but not with me. Even when I work properly and am on time, he doesn't appreciate me. Any suggestions on what I should do in that situation?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve here, and in what way your boss is being rude?

Comment: looking for a advise has i said my friend said to ask he said this site has exports on these type job related issues. Well has I told you he is bossy which i can manage but he is cutting my salary without any good reasons. I cannot leave the job due to my 6 month contract sign

Comment: Being rude and cutting your salary are two very different things. The first is... a problem but bearable. The second is a massive issue and possibly illegal, again depending on details. More than happy to help on this site, but we need a lot more in the way of details (and location) added to the question to be able to do so.

Comment: What country? If your boss is changing the terms of any contract unilaterally, by noy paying you, then you can do the same by leaving. Talk to an attorney.

Comment: Your Location and company size would be a good information. HR is the best answer for any company that has one

Comment: Being locked into a six-month contract where your boss is allowed to unilaterally decide to change your salary (regardless of offered reason) sounds really super-dubious to me, legally speaking.

Comment: It sounds like the rudeness and the salary adjustment might be connected to your performance.  Is there more to this story, perhaps you are on a performance plan, your boss is attempting to communicate they are not happy with you.  They might be doing a poor job, but are you sure the level of work being assigned to you, is not normal for your position?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Check if your contract states how much you are supposed to be paid and when.

Step 2) Make sure you have records of how much and when you are being paid for your work.

Step 3) Compare those 2 things.  If they are not the same, your employer is likely already in breach of contract (IANAL).

If your employer is in breach of contract, you should seek legal advice.  It is possible you have grounds to sue them for breach of contract or withholding wages or something like that.  You may also want to ask your lawyer if you can get out of the penalty for breaking the contract early based on these factors.  In most cases (IANAL) usually if you begin a lawsuit against your employer, you will as a matter of course be allowed to leave the company without legal penalty for fear of repercussion if you continue your employment, but that depends on your local laws so you should consult legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

- Your boss does not like you.
- Your boss cuts your salary.

The first one is not a real issue: you are paid to do your work, so is he, if you become friends that's ok, if you don't, that's not a reason not to do your work. And in the case that it becomes too hard, you can always decide to quit, and work elsewhere. The fact that you signed a contract for six months, should not block you from leaving earlier. What's your notice period?

The second one is a real problem: as far as I know it's illegal to cut someone's salary, so I'd advise you to get some help: union, employee protection organisations, ..., do you have those in your country and are you subscribed to such organisation?

Answer (score -2):

You can always get out, the question is at what cost.

If this is really bothering you, look at the consequences of leaving. Your contract should clearly state the your pay and also consequences for ending the contract early.

I would suspect your contract does not state "and I can change your wage on a whim". Look at exactly what the contract says and decide if the consequence of leaving is worth it or not. Also look at exactly what it says about pay, you may be able to fight it, but leaving is probably the easier option.

Comment: so sir you suggest I try leaving some how rather saying and fighting ?

Comment: personally, that's what I would do, its only a 6 month contract, by the time you are done fighting the contract will more than likely be over anyway.